# Run build command from vim, send output to another tmux pane?

Tags: vim, tmux, make

I'm using **tmux** and **Vim** as my development IDE. I have 3 panes open in tmux: one for editing source code, one for debugging and one as a display console.

From Vim I would like to run the `make` command and send all the build information emitted by it to the display console pane. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run any shell command from one pane and display its output in another pane with the `run-shell` command. For example:

```
tmux run-shell -t 2 "echo hello"
```

...and "hello" will be printed to pane number 2. You can see pane numbers with `prefix + q`.

From `vim` you should be able to do:

```
:!tmux run-shell -t 2 "make ..."
```

Add `-b` to run the command in the background.

**Update:** Addressing a couple things that @SLN brought up in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416453/print-out-the-build-information-into-different-tmux-pane/416480?noredirect=1#comment747633_416480)...

- `tmux` puts the output pane into *copy-mode*, the same mode it is in when you do scrolling, so break out of it however you normally do (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is one way). Note: you'll know you're in this mode if you see something like `[12/34]` (i.e. page-num/total-pages) in the upper-right corner of the pane.
- As for Vim requiring you to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) after `make` or other command completes, this is just how Vim works with external commands (`:!cmd`). I'm not aware of any way to avoid this but I believe you can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the command finishes and it will return as soon as it's done. (This might be system dependent.)

**Update 2:** I do know a workaround for the second item. If you use a mapping to run the external command you can embed an exit key. Here's an example where I'm just doing `ls` as my shell command:

```
nnoremap <leader>ls :!ls<CR><C-L>
```

From Normal mode I hit `\ls` and the ls command will run but then the console output will close and return me to `vim` right away. Perhaps you can adapt to this whatever your command is.

Comment: @B Layer, Seem working for me, but after I run the run-shell command the with the background in my vim, it still print some information to me, I have to tap Enter key to get back to vim, is this normal? Another issue is the run-shell command seems has frezzed my 2nd pane, how can I jump out the frezze mode? Thanks

Comment: @SLN see my updated answer.

Comment: In case anyone needs it, the default pane numbers seem to start at 0 (not very surprising though). When running the above, `-t 2` doesn't exist, so it would print "lost server" and fail. And if it matters, this is bash on Windows. I should have read the "prefix + q" part first though...

Comment: @making3 Okay, but I chose pane number 2 just as an example. (Still, you don't have more than 2 panes in any of your windows?) Anyways, try this: put `setw -g pane-base-index 1` in your `.tmux.conf` file and pane numbering will start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can touch a file in advance  & `tail -f file` : it in one pane ... so inside vim launching the make with redirection of output to that file  it will display your make session ....